# ViewPager unable to load images lazily with Picasso

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, picasso

I have a `FragmentActivity` in the first tab of a `TabHost`, and the `FragmentActivity` itself holds a `ViewPager`.

The `ViewPager`'s `setAdapter()` method sets a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a set of `Fragment`s. The goal is to have swipeable images in the first pane of the `TabHost`.

To test it, I was loading a bunch of images that I had kept locally in the project's `drawable` directory. **Everything worked beautifully.**

After having tested this initial setup, I'm downloading a bunch of image URLs' off a REST web service. I want these images to load lazily in the `ViewPager`, and I tried calling Picasso's `load()` method in three places:

1. The `onCreateView()` method of the `ViewPager`'s `Fragment`s (the same place where I was earlier loading images from the local `drawable` directory).

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {                

       View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_image);
       String url = getArguments().getString(IMAGE_RESOURCE_URL);
       Context context = getActivity();
       Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().into(imageView);

       return myFragmentView;
   }
   ```
2. The `onViewCreated()` method of the `ViewPager`'s `Fragment`s.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

       Context context = getActivity();
       String url = getArguments().getString(IMAGE_RESOURCE_URL);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image);
       Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().into(imageView);      

   }
   ```
3. The `onInstantiateItem()` method of the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

   ```
   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);
       Context context = Tab1Activity.this;
       String url = getItem(position).getArguments().getString("IMAGE_RESOURCE_URL");
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image);
       Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().into(imageView);
       return v;
   }
   ```

None of these methods worked. I know that its not a problem with Picasso because the other day I tried using Picasso in a `ListView` and it worked like a charm. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach should work fine... if you implement it correctly. I would expect your code to crash with a `NullPointerException`.

Replace:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_image);
```

with:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image);
```

Comment: Well, I am an idiot. Thank you so much, CommonsWare. Though Picasso still doesn't work even after I corrected my mistake. Every time I try it with Picasso the LogCat shows a strange WARNING message: "VFY: unable to resolve static method 571: Landroid/net/TrafficStats;.setThreadStatsTag (I)V". I ended up doing it with Volley which works perfectly.

Comment: @JohnG: That's just a warning, indicating that you're running on a device that lacks that particular class (`TrafficStats`) or method (`setThreadStatsTag()`). Unless you crashed, Picasso would have correctly skipped over that statement.

Comment: My problem is similar but this not help, check my SO question @CommonsWare, please.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890598/first-time-error-loading-picture-with-picasso

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your lazy loader should work in the context of the

Fragment.createView()

where  the Fragment is one of  a collection being paged by the ViewPager and the FragmentpagerAdapter

That is your option one.

I use another lazyloader that manages local memcache and local filesys cache for the bitmaps needed to load the images. at the time of the "OnCreateView()" it will go to the network to get the URL for the loader if the bitmap is not already cached.